# correct usage of verb

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Am I correctly using the *verb* in both cases?

> There might be situations where the above strategies **become
>   invalid** due to inconsistency of parameters or data issues.
>
> Inconsistency of parameters or data issues **become invalid** some of
>   the above strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's correct usage.

For the first sentence, which is awkward and non-idiomatic at best, I'd say:

> There might be situations **in which** the above strategies **are invalid** **because of** inconsistent parameters or data **problems**.

For the second sentence, which is grammatically incorrect, I'd say:

> Inconsistent parameters or data **problems may invalidate** some of the above strategies.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with OP's example #1. To my ear, it's purely a stylistic choice whether to use *are* or *become*. Or indeed, whether to use  *invalid* or *invalidated*, which you implicitly acknowledge yourself by using the latter in your rephrasing of OP's ungrammatical #2. But since he was specifically asking about ***the verb*** I think it would have been better to stick with *the same word* for both rephrasings.

Comment: @Fumble: You may be right about _are_ vs. _become_. We have no context, no info that says "these strategies are OK till X or Y occur; then they **become** invalid". If that's truly the case, then _become_ is preferable. But if we already know that X or Y, or both, is true, then _are_ is preferable. That's semantics, not style. Re: _invalidates_, another semantics problems the verbosity problem. Same meaning in fewer words is almost always better. My change means that I don't think OP was using the verb properly in this S.

Comment: Well, it's not like we have *no* contextual support for *become* - preceding *there **might** be situations* implies that there haven't been any such in the past (or at least, that they haven't been identified *yet*). And if such situations (the ones with inconsistent parameters or data problems) *do arise*, it's perfectly reasonable to say they [will] "invalidate" the strategies. Just as it is reasonable to say the strategies "become invalid" when faced with such situations. I still think all permutations are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct. *become* is appropriate because the indirect object *situations* is plural.
For the second sentence

> *The* inconsistency of parameters or data issues **becomes** invalid *due to* some of the above strategies.

is better. Since inconsistency is singular, becomes should be used, and the article *the* is also needed. Also *due to* is needed to indicate the cause of the inconsistency (same as in the first sentence).

Comment: This changes the meaning of the sentence. I think what is called for here is *Inconsistency of ... **makes** some of the above strategies **invalid*** ; or even better, as @BillFranke offers, ... ***invalidates** some of the above strategies.*